# Binary addition in MIPS without using arithmetic

Tags: assembly, mips

I need a function that is part of a larger MIPS program that takes two binary numbers and adds them together without use of the add instruction but I'm stuck. Say I have two binary numbers loaded into $a0 and $a1 and I want to return the sum in $v0 using only shifts and logical operators. Does anyone know of a function like this? I apologize for the lack of detail but I'm pretty stumped on this one. Thanks.

Comment: The logic would be based on a truth table for single bit addition, 0+0 = 0, 0 + 1 = 1, 1 + 0 = 1, 1 + 1 = 0 with a carry bit set.

Comment: @rcgldr yes, no arithmetic instructions

Comment: I updated my previous comment, didn't note the shift and logical operation requirement. You'll need to implement the equivalent of a full adder, handling the carry bits.

Comment: This should be possible with a 5 instruction loop. Does your version of MIPS always execute an additional instruction before taking a branch? If so, then see if you can put a useful instruction after the branch instead of using nop.

Comment: @rcgldr that's pretty good, I need at least double as many...

Comment: @rcgldr no it doesn't, I'll try to implement what you've written, thanks.

Comment: @rcgldr I can't quite see how to implement the carry bit set though

Comment: The carry-out should be set if at least two of the three input bits are set (which means their sum >= 2 of course, hence the carry).

Comment: Assuming this is homework, what operation is needed to produce a "half sum" bit and what operation is needed to produce a "carry" bit? I can offer more hints if you're still stuck.

Comment: @rcgldr I understand the logic just fine but I'm afraid I might need another hint on the implementation

Comment: You need to perform an | xor | to get the half sum, then an | and | to get the carry bits. If there are any carry bits, then shift them left 1 bit, and repeat the process. It should be possible to do this with a  5 instruction loop, using 3 registers.

Comment: I don't know which branch instructions your MIPS has. In addition to the 3 registers, you may also need to use R0 to check for zero.

Comment: You can edit your original question to show the code you wrote if you want. (place 4 spaces before each line to show code).